# What does an electric field with only a $\phi$-component mean?

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across this electric field expression in a problem (in cylindrical coordinates):
$\vec{E} = e^{-t}\hat{\phi}$. Changing to cartesian coordinates shows that the electric field is really just 0, since it has no magnitude. However, while working with cylindrical coordinates, I even get a curl with a z-magnitude. I feel like I'm overlooking something silly. What's going on? Is this where the intuitive picture of curls break?

Comment: Changing to Cartesian coordinates means converting $\hat{\phi}$ to $-\sin(\phi)\hat{x}+\cos(\phi)\hat{y}$.

Comment: What about the assignments $x = r\cos \phi$, $y = r \sin \phi$?

Comment: Those are for the scalar coordinates $x$ and $y$, not the unit vectors $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$.

Comment: I'm confused. I always thought I could go from cylindrical coordinates to cartesian by simply assorting the results of the assignments above in an xyz vector. Converting the unit vector as you've shown above doesn't make sense to me. If the first component of a vector in cylindrical coordinates is the distance of a point away from the central axis, and if the second component is the polar angle (ignoring the z for the moment), then I would think this is really just the 0 vector. Using the unit vector assignment you described would result in non-0 xy components?? Thanks

Comment: You are confusing a _point_ in cylindrical coordinates with a _vector-valued function_ in cylindrical coordinates. What you're given here is a function $\vec{E}(r,\phi,z)$ that takes a point in cylindrical coordinates as input and outputs a vector in cylindrical coordinates. The process you're describing applies to the _inputs_ of this function, and will give you a function $\vec{E}(x,y,z)$ that takes a point in Cartesian coordinates and outputs a vector in cylindrical coordinates. You still need to convert the output _vector_ into Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Since the direction of the $\hat{r}$ vector, and by extension the direction of the $\hat{\phi}$ vector, changes depending on where you are relative to the origin, the conversion from $\hat{\phi}$ to $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ will depend on the input coordinates of the function, which is why you need those $\sin(\phi)$ and $\cos(\phi)$ terms in my first comment.

Comment: As a side note, what I gave you in my first comment was a way to convert the function to one that takes cylindrical coordinates as input and outputs a Cartesian vector. If you wanted both input and output to be Cartesian, the conversion would be $\hat{\phi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(-y\hat{x}+x\hat{y})$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you very much. If you would write out your comments as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing to Cartesian coordinates means converting $\hat{\phi}$ to $-\sin(\phi)\hat{x}+\cos(\phi)\hat{y}$. You are confusing a point in cylindrical coordinates with a vector-valued function in cylindrical coordinates. What you're given here is a function $\vec{E}(r,\phi,z)$ that takes a point in cylindrical coordinates as input and outputs a vector in cylindrical coordinates. The process you're describing applies to the inputs of this function, and will give you a function $\vec{E}(x,y,z)$ that takes a point in Cartesian coordinates and outputs a vector in cylindrical coordinates. You still need to convert the output vector into Cartesian coordinates.

Since the direction of the $\hat{r}$ vector, and by extension the direction of the $\hat{\phi}$ vector, changes depending on where you are relative to the origin, the conversion from $\hat{\phi}$ to $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ will depend on the input coordinates of the function, which is why you need those $\sin(\phi)$ and $\cos(\phi)$ terms in my first comment.

As a side note, what I gave you in my first comment was a way to convert the function to one that takes cylindrical coordinates as input and outputs a Cartesian vector. If you wanted both input and output to be Cartesian, the conversion would be $\hat{\phi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(-y\hat{x}+x\hat{y})$.